# Subscription made by of().subscribe() instantly closes and stops

Tags: javascript, html, angular, rxjs, angular-material

So I have a dataSource for my material table that I get externally, and one of my filter fields needs to take unique values from one of the attributes of the objects, and I think the best way to get refreshed data on subsequent 'refresh' calls for the data would be to use a subscription. However since I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to subscribe to a `MatTableDataSource`, I went with using `of().subscribe()` from rxjs. However, as soon as the table launches, the sub fires off once (since it assigns the initial values to the `<mat-select>` options), but none of the subsequent data changes fired it, I looked at the angular dev tools and it turns out that the subscription is closed and stopped

```
uniqueSubscription : 
  _finalizers: null
  _parentage: null
  closed: true
  destination: null
  initialTeardown: undefined
  isStopped: true
```

so I'm at a loss on how to proceed to have the `<mat-select>` options get refreshed whenever new data comes in.

```
<mat-select class="filterMultiselect"
            formControlName="filterParam3"
            multiple
            panelClass="filterMultiselect"
            placeholder="Filter"
            (selectionChange)="updateManualPage(1)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of dropdownMultipleUniqueOptions"
              [value]="option">
    {{option}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

```
tableDataSource: MatTableDataSource<randomInterface> = new MatTableDataSource<randomInterface>();
uniqueSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription;
dropdownMultipleUniqueOptions: string[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.uniqueSubscription = of(this.tableDataSource.data).subscribe(() => {
    this.dropdownMultipleUniqueOptions = this.tableDataSource.data.map(data => data.param3).filter((data, index, array) => array.indexOf(data) === index);
  })
}
```

Comment: of() creates an observable that completes.

Comment: Ah, okay. So I presume I'd have to create an actual Observable and subscribe to it instead? Though I'm not sure how I'd manage to do that with a MatTableDataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that the of() operator completes immediately afterwards. As already mentioned by @Matthieu Riegler and @TotallyNewb. See also explanation: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of

Here is another approach:

Use connect() method to get a Observable of the DataSource: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#datasource
and then:

```
tableDataSource: MatTableDataSource<randomInterface> = new MatTableDataSource<randomInterface>();
dropdownMultipleUniqueOptions$: Observable<string[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dropdownMultipleUniqueOptions$ = this.tableDataSource.connect().pipe(
    map((data) => {
      return data.map(data => data.param3).filter((data, index, array) => array.indexOf(data) === index);
    })
}
```

```html
<mat-select class="filterMultiselect"
            formControlName="filterParam3"
            multiple
            panelClass="filterMultiselect"
            placeholder="Filter"
            (selectionChange)="updateManualPage(1)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of dropdownMultipleUniqueOptions$ | async"
              [value]="option">
    {{option}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: A "try this" answer without any explanation is not very helpful. You should explain what the `connect()` does, what it returns, when the returned observable emits and when it closes. It would be also helpful to explain the observable returned by `of()` closes immediately.